# Just one side of my headphones work (Arch-Linux)

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, headphones

I'm using Arch-Linux on my Laptop (Thinkpad E470) and tried to hear music with my Teufel Massive headphones. I can hear just with the left side, the right side seems to be not working. I've tried the headphones with my smartphone, and they work. Has anyone an idea what I could do to hear with both sides?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Connected via bluetooth or wired?

Comment: Do those headphones work ok in other distros (live, etc)? Do other headphones work ok in the same jack with arch?

Comment: The Headphone is wired. I have tried it with Windows 10 and it works. I don't have other Headphones with me at the moment, but I will try other, when I'm home again.

Comment: Run `alsamixer` and determine if the left and right are balanced on Master, Headphones, (or front if plugging into your speakers) and PCM.

Comment: Do the headphones have a 4-contact TRRS jack, or a regular 3-contact TRS one?

Comment: @jdwolf: That solved my problem. Thank you very much! The left-side-volume was at ~55%, while the right-side-volume was just at ~3%. Now thy both have the same value.

Comment: Alright wrote it up as an answer for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When this happens the likely issue is that ALSA's left right balance is set wrong.

You can adjust this with the textmode program `alsamixer` as well as in a graphical application like kmix.

Determine if the left and right are balanced 50%-50% on Master, Headphones, (or front if plugging into your speakers) and PCM