# Just left side of my headphones work (Manjaro)

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, manjaro

I tried to hear music and only the left side of three headphones work.

I found the same problem here [Just one side of my headphones work (Arch-Linux)](https://superuser.com/questions/1281148/just-one-side-of-my-headphones-work-arch-linux/1281418) but, in my case, alxamixer is showing same number in the left and right sides.

I've tried playing music using moc program and youtube as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens with speakers instead of headphones?  What happens if you use the headphones with another device?  Does it change if you push the plug farther in or pull it slightly out?  What happens with other headphones in the same jack?

Comment: Speakers work well. The headphones work well with other devices. I tried pushing as you said, but nothing change. I tried with three headphones and always the left side only works.

Comment: You could have a bad connection in the jack.

Comment: I am thinking and before the last system update, it was working well. Could be that?

Comment: It could be anything, but loss of one channel on only one jack doesn't seem like the kind of problem an update could cause.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding here that after coming back from vacation I updated my work manjaro and there was some "intel" stuff to be updated. Now speakers sound normal but any headphone works left side only. It is definitely a software thing because in settings it shows it locked to the left side, while on speakers it shows the switch in the middle. Also there is like 30 posts asking why headphones are left side only after update in manjaro forums.

Answer (score 0):

Add been having the same problem for some months but was adjusting with the balance option.  Today I managed to solve it.

Steps taken:
1.remove ~/.pulse
2.reinstall pulseaudio
3.kill pulseaudio and wait for it to restart (or restart it manually)

Should be working flawlessly again. If something is odd with the volume try looking it up in alsamixer